# My background does not repeat when there is text on it, why?

Tags: html, css

http://www.casleague.com
^ you can view the complete source there

How come the the image http://casleague.com/images/content/bg.gif does not repeat -y like I coded it?

CSS

```
.main { background: transparent url("../images/content/bg.gif") repeat-y;
        width: 960px; 
        font-family: Tahoma;
        color: #0c8cbd;
        text-decoration: none;
        word-spacing: normal;
        text-align: justify;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font-size: 11px; }

     .content { padding: 20px; height:100%; }      
         .leftside { width: 600px; float: left; }
         .rightside { width: 300px; float: right; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="leftside">
         123
         12
         312
         3123
         123
         123
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
         123
         123
         123
         123
         123
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, your background *is* repeating. However, your `<div class="main">` is only 40 pixels high. This is what it looks like when you click on the element in Firebug:

[image: screenshot]

Notice how small the highlighted area is. And the `clientHeight` in the DOM window at the bottom right reads "40".

The issue is that by default most containers won't expand to the size of their contents if the contents are only floats. I've had [issues with this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563844/how-can-i-use-float-left-in-a-div-without-breaking-the-containing-elements-h). Add `overflow: auto;` to the style block for `.main`, and it should work. If not, add a `<br clear="all" />` after the closing tag for `<div class="rightside">`.

Comment: Lol you are a fine fine gentleman. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @soju - No thanks. I already have enough work to keep me busy for years.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the `leftside` and `rightside` `div`s will fix the problem. Those `div`s are floating and are the only content of the `content` `div`, causing it to have zero calculated height. The vertical paddings of `content` are `40px` total, making `main` have `40px` height - and your background actually is repeating on those `40px`.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your "." to "#" and "class" to "id". And putting right before left in the page.

```
#main { background: transparent url("../images/content/bg.gif") repeat-y;
        width: 960px; 
        font-family: Tahoma;
        color: #0c8cbd;
        text-decoration: none;
        word-spacing: normal;
        text-align: justify;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        font-size: 11px; }

    #content { padding: 20px; height:100%; }      
         #leftside { width: 600px; float: left; }
         #rightside { width: 300px; float: right; }

    <div id="main">
       <div id="content">
          <div id="rightside">
             123
             123
             123
             123
             123
          </div>
<div id="leftside">
             123
             12
             312
             3123
             123
             123
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You do realize that makes absolutely no difference right? That isn't going to magically solve the problem.