# Arranging items on a html page

Tags: html

Its been a long time since I programmed html. My document currently has a google chart on it contained within a div tag. I wish to add a combo box and text box to my page to manipulate the js behind the chart. Previously I have used tables to organise items on a page, but how is it done today?

By the way, my div looks like this:

```
<div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: One nice approach is the [twitter bootstrap grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html).

Comment: I'd say floating and relative/absolute positioning are used more frequently (CSS). Tables still work though (kind of)

Comment: Tables aren't recommended anymore. Use `div`s and css to position them.

Comment: Use Div's for everything - and look into a tutorial for CSS positioning , don't be scared of putting too many DIV's

Comment: @Rune: tables aren't recommended for *layout* purposes, sure; but they're *absolutely* recommended for tabular data (not that this question concerns tabular data, but I'd rather not see people issuing blanket bans on `table`s just as an overreaction to a past-misuse). =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML 4, you would want to use div elements, and then assign them styles with IDs or classes:

```
<div id="mainContent>
     <div class="container">
         <!-- Content Here-->
     </div>
     <div class="container">

     </div>
</div>
```

CSS; this would give you centered page 960px wide, with a border on each container

```
html, body {text-align: center}
#mainContent {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
.container {margin: 10px; border: 1px #000 solid}
```

To get two columns, you would use the following for `.container`

```
.container {margin: 10px 0 10px 10px; width: 465px; float: left}
```

When ever you float something, you always want to give it a specific width, and if the container of the floated elements doesn't have a specific height, you would add

```
<div style="height: 0; clear: both">&nbsp;</div>
```

otherwise the container will not extend to the bottom on the floated elements, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563844/how-can-i-use-float-left-in-a-div-without-breaking-the-containing-elements-h)

Heres an article on floats: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/

I'm going to try to find some more layout stuff and edit it in.

EDIT: the main difference using HTML 5 is that it adds elements like `header`, `footer`, and `section`. In HTML 4 there is only `div`.

EDIT:

Heres another decent tutorial on using floats in layouts:

http://www.ozzu.com/html-tutorials/tutorial-multi-column-layout-using-css-float-part-t85704.html

Comment: Also beware that as I was searching I found many articles still recommending tables. As the others have said, do not use tables for layout purposes.