# Have Inline-Block h1 break line when window gets smaller

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

As you can see here we have an image and a header next to it.
https://jsfiddle.net/bL77g9bf/1/

Now when I make the window smaller all the text goes below the image, rather than just pieces of the sentence going to the next line (while staying to the right of the image).

How do I achieve this effect, without using floats?

Code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-25252601,width-640,resizemode-4/stunning-images-of-the-space.jpg">

        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
</div>

img {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}

h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Set display: inline, not inline-block. It is what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/bL77g9bf/2/

Comment: Slightly better, but I want the text to still stay to the right of the image (until it can't anymore because the image ends). So if you cut off the word "heading" it will go below "This is a" rather than going below the image.

Comment: Why not to use float: left, in img element?

Comment: Because on my actual site, floating left messes up another element I have below it.

Comment: I can not imagine any other way to do it. If you post the problematic code with float, maybe I can help you.

Comment: Well when I use inline-block it's fine (assuming the window is big): http://gyazo.com/4bdb67d4c50baf691fc5014f15262915 but when i change the image to float instead the bottom div breaks because I have it purposely overlapping http://gyazo.com/a5f14a21154deb1c606033b1e570b6c6

Comment: That might be because float:left sorta messes up with the height of the container. Try doing `overflow:auto` on the containing element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563844/how-can-i-use-float-left-in-a-div-without-breaking-the-containing-elements-h

Comment: @Brad Mitchell, I can not access to your links, but I made a few changes in the provided fiddle. Check: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/bL77g9bf/6/

Answer (score 1):

This is the only situation where I would recommend a float. Where you have an image and text together and would like the text to flow around the image gracefully.

The issue that you are having with the float is that it isn't cleared properly, use the following solution to fix that issue.

```css
.wrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: red;
}
.wrap::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.wrap > img {
    width:200px;
    float: left;
}
.wrap > h1 {
    vertical-align:top;
    white-space: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/thumb/msid-25252601,width-640,resizemode-4/stunning-images-of-the-space.jpg">
    <h1>This is a heading blah blah blah blah blah</h1>
</div>
```